Sort Text Numbers in ascending in Slicer
I am trying to sort the text based numbers in slicer, but within the slicer settings I am unable to sort the values.

How can I sort these values within the slicer?

This is not a good practice in your case, but there is a way how to sort any field in order different then it's value.
To do this you should have one more field in the table containing field you wish to sort. In your case you should have to Start month fields:

One containing - your initial text values
Another containing, for example, numeric values of month. But as I've understood this field cannot be generated by adding a caclculated column in pbi using dax expression, you have to add it to the table on transformation (powerquery) stage.

So suppose you have a such table:

Then you can select your text field in Data palette and change sort it's sort order using "Sort by column" menu item within "Column tools" menu:

And the result of this is that text field is sorted in order of numeric one:


the easiest way is to change the column date type to number.


i can not change the datatype as i am passing them to Power query SQL parameters

"#(lf)select * #(lf)from aaa.tabname where ""date"" >= to_date(CONCAT('"&StartYear&"', '/', '"&StartMonth&"' ,'/','"&StartDay&"'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')#(lf)and ""date"" <= to_date(CONCAT('"&EndYear&"', '/', '"&EndMonth&"' ,'/','"&EndDay&"'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')#(lf)#(lf)",

Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator & to types Text and Number.
Details:
Operator=&
Left=
select *
from aaa.tabname where "date" >= to_date(CONCAT(
Right=2022

it should be the same data type. do you have any invalid values or text values? or maybe  try to set the data type in the sql statement.

If you write something like this, adding function Text.From():
"#(lf)select * #(lf)from aaa.tabname where ""date"" >= to_date(CONCAT('"&Text.From(StartYear)&"', '/', '"&Text.From(StartMonth)&"' ,'/','"&Text.From(StartDay)&"'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')#(lf)and ""date"" <= to_date(CONCAT('"&Text.From(EndYear)&"', '/', '"&Text.From(EndMonth)&"' ,'/','"&Text.From(EndDay)&"'), 'YYYY/MM/DD')#(lf)#(lf)"
You will not have to keep this field as text, it could be of type number.
But there is also an opportunity to sort field in slicer as you wish.
